# read row and convert float to integer in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple rows and columns. One of my columns (lets call that column A) has rows that contain  mix of strings, strings and integers (i.e RSE1023), integers only and floats only. I want to find a way to convert the rows of the column A that are floats to integers. Probably with something that can scan through the column in the dataframe and find the rows that are columns and make them integers?

Comment: How's your `column A` looks like? and Whats your expected output? Please include this in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
df['A']=df['A'].apply(lambda r:int(r) if isinstance(r,float) else r)
```

Comment: what if the column contains also NaN values? I tried to do it but it finds a problem because of the NaN values. Forgot to tell about this also.

Comment: you can do `df.where(pd.notnull(df),None)` to convert Nan to None first, I think it may have a side effect of changing all columns to object type however.  Alternatively you can take care of the Nan case in the if , like `(if isinstance(r,float) and not np.isnan(r))`

Answer (score 0):

In `pandas` you do not give datatypes to rows but to columns.

A trick you could use would be to [.transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) the dataframe, turning the rows into columns and vice versa.